# inkscape arows not align with line

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to add some arrow along the line. the end arrow seems good but the arrows in the middle of the line isn't align with line. How can I make the middle arrow on the line?

[image]

I am using "Fill and stroke" property to add arrows:

[image]

Comment: You may have better luck with this on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow is aligned with the mean of the two handles at that point, and you have a corner at this point. As Inkscape does not support individually set midmarkers, there is no work around with your curve defined as a single path using the midmarkers.

The solution is thus to

1) Break path at the point where you want the markers (edit path tool `F2`, then Break path icon)
2) Break apart path (`Ctrl-Shift-K`)

Then you can group the broken bits of your path (`Ctrl-G`), but combining them again will lead to other problems.